# fileupload newline in constant

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I get the problem newline in constant:

```
    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/) + filename);
//here
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Im also wondering is there a way I can resize the image upon upload if so, how?

And as this is a save as in my fileupload control will this overwrite any folder that has the userid already there? (what I want and need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Newline in constant**

`FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/) + filename);
//here`

Should be:

`FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/") + filename);
//here`

**Image resize / thumbnails**

If it's a thumbnail image you're after, then you can use [Image.GetThumbnailImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx).  A basic implementation is like this:

```
using (System.Drawing.Image fullsizeImage =
         System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(originalFilePath))
{
       // these calls to RotateFlip aren't essential, but they prevent the image 
       // from using its built-in thumbnail, which is invariably poor quality.
       // I like to think of it as shaking the thumbnail out ;)
       fullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
       fullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

       using (System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage = 
         fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero))
       {
            thumbnailImage.Save(newFilePath);
       }
}
```

**Overwrite**

Overwrite is the default behaviour, so uploading the same file to the same UserID will replace it.

Comment: no not thumbnails just a resize in jpeg pixel need the images to be set to a certain width and height (pixel)

Comment: Then this will be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c

Answer (score 2):

Well I can already see in the line above your error you are missing a quote after /uploadedimage/ and the next to last paren should be after filename not /uploadedimage/

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a quote or is it a typo:

```
Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")
```

I would also recommend using `string.Format` when using lots of string concatenation (usually do this when I have to use `+` more than once):

```
Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/userdata/{0}/uploadedimage/", theUserId))
```

**EDIT:** to answer resize comment:

Here is a link to a similar SO question:

[how to resize an image whileing saving in an folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012556/how-to-resize-an-image-whileing-saving-in-an-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Which value has the newline variable?

Below adds a Trim() to the value collected and also provides a way to see what each of the string values collected afterwards are.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString().Trim(); // add Trim()
  if (FileUploadControl.HasFile && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(theUserId)) // add test
  {
    try
    {
      string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
      Console.WriteLine(filename);
      string filepath = string.Format("~/userdata/{0}/uploadedimage/", theUserId);
      Console.WriteLine(filepath );
      string mapPath = Server.MapPath(filepath);
      Console.WriteLine(mapPath );
      FileUploadControl.SaveAs(mapPath + filename);
      StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

Just Trim() the string value has the newline constant in it.